# how to use two css style in a div or span

Tags: css, html

how i can use two style on a div `<div id="span,google"></span>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't assign two id's like that, but you can use two classes:

```
<div class="span google"></div>
```

Also, you can't start the element as a `div` and close it as a `span` as in your code. I'll write that off as a typo, tho.

```
.span { some-css }
.google { other-css }
```

Comment: but how i can do if i have this two as a  ID

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have two ids, an id already uniquely identifies an element.

Comment: id is meant to be unique to that specific tag, so you should use class instead. However, if you must associate it with two id's, then you could nest the divs: <div id="span"><div id="google"></div></div> and thus: #span {} #google {}

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<div class="span google"></div>
```

where you should have `.span` and `.google` classes set in your stylesheet

Comment: that's not the proper syntax tho

Comment: @David: How is it not proper?

Comment: Anyone can make a small mistake like this; I think Sarfraz meant to type the correct form. Don't downvote...

Comment: Yes guys i did not see the last closing tag, fixed it now. Thanks you all :)

Comment: I was referring to `span, google` instead of `span google` but I see that that's changed now as well